# returning result of asynchronous web queries with node

Tags: node.js

while I conceptually understand node (and ajax's) async behavior, I am always flummoxed at what I believe must be a routine task. Consider the following pseudo-ish code:

```
let result = [];
request("http://server", function(error, response) {
    const links = response.links; // an array of links
    links.forEach(function(link) {
         request(link, function(error, response) {
             result.push(response.gold);
         });
         // *****C*****
    });
    // *****B*****
});
// *****A*****
```

My question is, when to return the result to the web so that the complete results are returned? At `A` and `B` the result may not be ready yet, but I can only return the result from `C`if I do it in some kind of streaming fashion, which I don't know how to do. What is the correct way of handling something like this (and, let us assume that while I have shown only one level of descent into the first `response`, how would I handle this with any number of levels)? Additionally, I would like to know a way to do this without the use of any external helper library such as `async`. I have nothing against using something like that, but I want to understand how something should be done in `nodejs` given its async nature.

Comment: You can use the old style with callbacks. Or you can use promises (and then also use the `async` and `await` keywords (not the library) to code like you are in a sync world. (So you can use try catches and returns. Really nice I would say))

Comment: could you kindly provide me with a sample snippet of code?

Comment: mh are you going to use the latest version of node 8.x? in the 6 version `async` and `await` is not available. .... I could just write how i would do it but idk if this is the best way...

Comment: ha, good catch! Strangely, I am using 8.x on my laptop but have 6.x on the server where I will host the app. So, that reinforces the need to have something really fundamental. As I said, this sounds like a routine web task, and there has to be a basic way with core functionality to pull this off.

Comment: I would just push the content chunks into response as soon as they are ready.

Comment: typically using `hapijs` or `expressjs` I send back stuff to the web with `reply(result).headers`. What you are suggesting would involve sending the `headers` once and then adding new results as I receive them, a streaming response. Yes, I would certainly like to learn how to do that (I don't know how). But, on the other end, I would like the user to also know that the query is now complete and no more results are forthcoming. That would allow the user to do something further with the result (fyi, I am making an API here that others would use)

Comment: Yes you will have to send the header separately, in express, you can just use response.write() to stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this using promisses and  `async` and `await` in nodejs v8.

First you need to make your request function return a promise instead of using a callback. So either promisify it or use a library that returns a promise. 
Now you can write an async function like this

```
var requestPromisified = require('request-promise');

async function getGoldData() {
    var response = await requestPromisified('http://example.com');
    var links = ['http://example.com']; //get links somehow from response
    var goldPromises = links.map(async function (link) {
        var response = await requestPromisified(link);
        var gold = 0; //get gold somehow from response
        return gold;
    });
    return Promise.all(goldPromises);
}
```

And then use the function in other async contexts, for example in an express route callback. (Additional recommendation: use the module [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) so you don't have to use `next(err);` this module automatically passes rejected promisees to the next middleware.)

```
var router = require('express-promise-router')();

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    var goldData = await getGoldData();
    console.log(goldData);
    res.json(goldData);
});
```

Or call it anywhere like:

```
getGoldData().then(function(goldData){
    console.log('goldData:', goldData);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('ERROR:', err);
});
```

Comment: One thing I would say is you may aswell go full ES6+ and advocate arrow syntax over functions and const/let over var.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to parse two youtube URLs and lets handle them. Promises would make code a little easier to reason about.

```
const sonyPictures = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq';
const fox = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfPBohF1uFwoO5wBnYD67i0pbZ6GqrGEd';
const allURLs = [sonyPictures, fox];
```

So now we have an array on which we want to loop. Now we need to make the request and save the promise

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const playlistArrayPromises = [];
```

...

```
allURLs.forEach((channelURL) => {
    const options = {
      uri: channelURL,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      },
    };
    playlistArrayPromises.push(rp(options));
```

The next step is to wait for all these promises to resolve (or reject) and we can perform the actions that we want

```
Promise.all(playlistArrayPromises).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.length);
    console.log('here');
    return 0;
  });
```

Now the result has all the parsedURL responses in the order in which the request was made.

You can extend this to any level you want. All you have to do is to wait for all the promises to resolve via Promise.all at the child level and once its done, you can proceed further.

Here is the full code which you can run with node and the required package installed.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const sonyPictures = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq';
const fox = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfPBohF1uFwoO5wBnYD67i0pbZ6GqrGEd';
const allURLs = [sonyPictures, fox];
const playlistArrayPromises = [];

const main = () => {
  allURLs.forEach((channelURL) => {
    const options = {
      uri: channelURL,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      },
    };
    playlistArrayPromises.push(rp(options));
  });
  Promise.all(playlistArrayPromises).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.length);
    return 0;
  });
};




main();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have used function push, it basically adds the elements in LIFO form. Instead of it use, unshift function.
So, if you didn't understand https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp
see this link.

Comment: I am not sure if `push` vs `unshift` matter here. They don't seem to be relevant to what I am asking.

Comment: This answer is confused